# Get connection string from registry for API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I had first created a web application in VB.Net. Now i am creating its mobile application using Ionic framework. Language is c#.

In web application i use to get the connection string from `Registry` add save it in a session. I used to do it in `global.asax`.

global.asax:

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

  Dim mDBConnector As String = String.Empty

  With Application
     .Add("ProductRegistryKey", "Accord 2.0")
     .Add("ProductGUID", "ea3asue4n43-mbk3-3nmn-n34n4h3j4n4n3")
     .Add("ProductId", "1")

     mDBConnector = WebHelper.GetDBConnector(Application.Item("ProductRegistryKey")

  End With
End Sub
```

I am not using any session in my API, Since i have read that API is stateless and it is not a good practice. So how can i achieve this in my API?

Comment: the fifth `DBName` does not exists in the connection strings, so when `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[DBName]` is called it returns *null*. Which will cause error when you try to call member on null object. Check to make sure the name exists in the *web.config*. You should also do some defensive coding and check for null before trying to access the property.

Comment: If its working for four of them, it should work here as well. Check what is null. Object reference is generic.

Comment: @Nkosi : Since i am blocked to ask any further question, I have to edit my previous question to a new ones. So can you just go through my edited question above and help me out with it.

Comment: @PraneetNadkar : Since i am blocked to ask any further question, I have to edit my previous question to a new ones. So can you just go through my edited question above and help me out with it. Also if u can up vote this question so i am able to put up my queries once again please.

Answer (score 0):

The fifth `DBName` does not exist in the connection strings configuration, so when `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[DBName]` is called it returns *null*, which will cause the null reference error when you try to call member on null object.

Check to make sure the name being called exists in the *web.config*.

```
<connectionStrings>
  <!-- ... -->
  <add name="FifthDbName" ...... />
</connectionStrings>
```

You should also do some defensive coding and check for *null* before trying to access the property.

```
var setting = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[DBName];
if(setting != null) {
    string DbConnector = setting.ConnectionString;
    bool Connection1 = DbConnector.ToLower().StartWith("metadata");
    if (Connection1 == true)
    {
      System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnectionStringBuilder 
      efBuilder = new 
      System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnectionStringBuilder(DbConnector);
      DbConnector = efBuilder.ProviderConnectionString;
    }
}
//...
```

Comment: I am passing the same DbName in all the five controllers which means all of them will return me the same connection string. But the problem is only four of them returns me the connection string but the fifth one doesn't. Even i am aware that the DbName that i am passing should be there in my web.config. But anyway thanks for that defensive coding check.